# Can't seem to horizontally center text that has been translated 270 deg?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So we have these HTML tables with "vertical headers". We are using the css3 translate property to rotate the text. All of this is working great, except, I cannot find a way to correctly center the text horizontally. I can of course manually center the text using padding, margin, or several other properties, but this only works if all of the vertical header cells are the same width, which is not the case.

I have created a test case in JS fiddle with a handy slider for dynamically adjusting the width of one of the columns:

http://jsfiddle.net/c7ft8nzc/

Just in case, here is the code sample I am using.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr class="header">
        <td>A header</td>
        <td>Some Other header</td>
        <td id="v"><div class="vert">A Vert. Header</div></td>
        <td><div class="vert">Another Vert. Header Here</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Here is some longer content that will likely break into multiple lines</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>More Content here</td>
        <td>Here is some other content</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>One more row here</td>
        <td>Other stuff</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
    <p>Adjust slider to change the width of the first vertical header</p>
    <div id="slider"></div>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/css/base/jquery-ui.css">
<style>
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 400px;
}
td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.header{
    height: 200px;
}
.header td{
    vertical-align:bottom;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.vert{
    height:21px;
    width:12px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-4px, 20px) rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -moz-transform:translate(-4px, 20px) rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform:translate(-4px, 20px) rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    -o-transform:translate(-4px, 20px) rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform:translate(-4px, 20px) rotate(270deg);
    transform-origin:0 0;
}
#v{
    width:40px;
}
#slider{
    width:400px;
}
</style>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var s = $( "#slider" ).slider({
        min: 12,
        max: 100,
        value: 40,
        change: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#v").width(s.slider( "option", "value" ) + 'px');
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

on `.vert` centers the text horizontally.

See updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7ft8nzc/1/).